# gnuradio 3.10 from package on Ubuntu 22.04 and uhd support

Tags: ubuntu, gnuradio

My question is for general understanding of gnuradio 3.10 and uhd support.
I have fresh instalation of Ubuntu 22.04.
After:

sudo apt install gnuradio

it installs gnuradio 3.10,
but there is no install of full scale uhd-host. For example there is not installed such tools for uhd support as uhd_find_devices, uhd_usrp_probes, uhd_images_downloader

It is not such case on Ubuntu 20.04
After:

sudo apt install gnuradio

it installs gnuradio 3.8.1 and full scale uhd 3.15

What is general concept for installing gnuradio 3.10 from package on Ubuntu 22.04 with full uhd support?

Best regards!

Ivan

Answer (score 1):

As can be seen [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/gnuradio), the gnuradio package recommends installing uhd-host. Did you maybe use `--no-install-recommends`?

Try `apt install uhd-host` afterwards.